# Some css properties set by jquery don't show up on html elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had set the CSS border property to a div tag by jquery as below:

```
<div class='content'></div>
$('.content').css({
   "border": "30px solid transparent",
   "border-image": "url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoXiQqNZYII=') 30 30 round", //I was shorted base64 image
});
```

The div tag applied all the CSS except the *border-image* property. It only applies *border* property to '.content' class:

```
<div class="content" style="border: 30px solid transparent;">
```

I tried to set the properties one by one but *border-image* still didn't work out. If I only set *border-image*, it works.

Comment: Are you sure `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoXiQqNZYII=` is a legit base64 image? It parses error in my case.

Comment: Maybe try `border-width`, `border-style` instead of `border`?

Comment: @HaoWu I was shorted this base64 because it very long

Comment: @tsh, thank you, I've just tried, the div show border-with and border-image property but don't see border-style

Comment: @tsh oh sorry, I have a mistake at CSS value, I've updated and It works like a charm, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I refer to the comment of @tsh.
I separate the `border` property to three properties are: `border-image`, `border-style`, `border-color` and it works as I want.

About the reason for the problem that I got, I think caused by the `border` property is includes `border-image` property, so it doesn't understand the second `border-image` property